# What tool I need to use for CSOM?

Tags: csom, tools

Just installed CSOM 64 bit on my machine. What tool I need to use in order to use CSOM?

Comment: You can use the CSOM components in in Visual Studio or PowerShell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does CSOM refer to the "Client Side Object Model" in your post?
Can you explain what do you mean when you say, you installed it?
To my knowledge CSOM is code that runs on the clients browser that can do "things" that were traditionally done on the server using ASP.NET code.

This is JavaScript that is written into your pages,
To answer your question, you can use Visual Studio to write the pages/code - which is what I use.
Have a browse through these pages: http://tutorial.wmlcloud.com/windows_server/sharepoint-2013---working-with-the-csom-(part-1)---understanding-client-object-model-fundamentals.aspx

I hope I have understood your question correctly.

Comment: CSOM is commonly refered to C# code running from a client application, like an MVC app or similar. Not javascript. So this surely should not be the accepted answer?

Comment: You can use Javascript to interact with the CSOM and this seems to be the direction that microsoft are heading with their "app" model. Javascript and HTML 5. C# is also (and traditionally) used but not exclusively.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60348/SharePoint-Client-Object-Model-for-JavaScript

Comment: CSOM 64-bit is certainly not JavaScript. Although you are correct that you can execute cide against client object model through both .Net code and JavaScript

Comment: Yes but I was referring to how you can use it rather than what the CSOM itself is written in

Answer (score 1):

May be it does not call CSOM. Actual name is **[SharePoint Server Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585)**

Now download Visual Studio for using it.

For SharePoint 2013: VS12 +

For SharePoint 2013: VS10

Comment: We are on SP 2013 enterprise. Is the visual studio free (minimum)? Whats the link

Comment: that's the one i downloaded.

Comment: Visual Studio Community is free. But I am not sure that you will be able to use it for SharePoint Development. https://www.visualstudio.com/vs-2015-product-editions

Comment: So edit your question properly @GloriaTrevino